# How to make GET API in laravel to get KEY values from Postman

Tags: laravel

Hello i am making a GET API in laravel and i want to add parameters to the API, but from what i saw on internet some were passing values like this:

This is the code from **api.php**

```
Route::get('outlay/{startdate?}/{enddate?}',[GetValuesController::class,'getOutlays']);
```

This is the code from **Controller**

```
 function getOutlays($startdate = null, $enddate = null)
    {
        if($startdate == null && $enddate == null)
        {
            $values =  response()->json([OutlayResource::collection(Outlay::where("status", Status::CONFIRMED_BY_EMPLOYEE)->orderBy('updated_at', 'asc')->get())], 200);
        }else
        {
            $values =  response()->json([OutlayResource::collection(Outlay::where("status", Status::CONFIRMED_BY_EMPLOYEE)-> wherebetween("updated_at", [$startdate, $enddate])->orderBy('updated_at', 'asc')->get())], 200);
        }
        return $values;
    }
```

This code works good but when i use **postman** i have to write the url like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/outlay/2023-02-14 09:33:23/2023-02-14 09:33:23
```

While i need it to be like this:

```
 http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/outlay/
```

And to add Key parameters to postman

```
startdate = 2023-02-14 09:33:23

enddate = 2023-02-14 09:33:23
```

I know how to do this in plain `php` but cant find a way in `laravel` to do so.

[image]

Comment: During `GET` request you need to add both paramater startdate and enddate in `Params` instead of `Body`

Comment: thank  you that works i was confused why wouldnt get it

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel basically we use Request object to get parameter values inside the functions.

For use request object you can try :

**Your Route :**

```
Route::get('outlay', [GetValuesController::class, 'getOutlays']);
```

**Your Controller:**

```
function getOutlays(Request $request)
{
    $startdate = $request->startdate;  
    $enddate = $request->enddate;

    if($startdate == null && $enddate == null)
    {
        $values = response()->json([OutlayResource::collection(Outlay::where("status", Status::CONFIRMED_BY_EMPLOYEE)->orderBy('updated_at', 'asc')->get())], 200);
    }
    else
    {
        $values = response()->json([OutlayResource::collection(Outlay::where("status", Status::CONFIRMED_BY_EMPLOYEE)->whereBetween("updated_at", [$startdate, $enddate])->orderBy('updated_at', 'asc')->get())], 200);
    }

    return $values;
}
```

**In postman:**

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/outlay?startdate=2023-02-14%2009:33:23&enddate=2023-02-14%2009:33:23
```

Comment: So will laravel take the KEY values from the postman?

Comment: You just pass as before in url or as parameter. It will take from both side well

Comment: I uploaded image from postman its not getting the KEY still

Comment: but i dont need to pass it in the url writen i need it url default that it either gets values or not

Comment: you know how in php you have a simple url `www.xyz.com` and in php you make you verify if specific variables are null or not and then procede

Comment: So you can pass  both paramater `startdate` and `enddate` in `Params` instead of Body